# What does it mean when there is a letter c in front of the tempo on a score?

Tags: terminology, tempo

For example, "c. 108". I need to practice and I have absolutely no idea what it means!

Comment: My guess would be "circa" ("approximately").

Answer (score 9):

The c. stands for *circa* which means about or approximately. You may also see it as ca. Pretty much it means means that you should play the piece around a tempo of 108 bpm. You could play it a little faster or slower the 108 it just to get you in the range of where the composer would want you to play it.